# What does this sigma notation mean?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable and $g(X)$ be a function of $X$

This is from the $E[g(X)]=\sum g(x)p(x) \, dx$ in my book it uses this notation,

$\sum_j \sum_{i:g(x_i )=y_j} g(x_i)p(x_i)$ what does the second sigma mean?

I basically don't know what the second sigma means, ive never seen the notation use $i:g(x_i )=y_j$ before.

its from the first course of probability by sheldon ross

ive made another question because i cant edit the old one (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590004/what-does-this-sigma-notation-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\sum_i \sum_{j:g(x_i )=y_j} g(x_i)p(x_i)
$$
The first sigma: sum over all values of $i$

The second sigma: sum over all values of $j$ such that $g(x_i )=y_j$.

Perhaps you should check that you copied this right...

Comment: yeah my bad i made some typos

Comment: ohhhh i see thank you!

Comment: so in other words (if you look back at my question, sorry) an $i$ is chosen if it fits the criteria of $g(x_i ) =y_j$

Comment: only then will it sum?